# how do I implement decimal formatting into a future value program (Java)

Tags: java, decimalformat

I have been assigned to edit a future value program and implement the decimal format. i have called the class but am having trouble figuring out where to place the code for the formatting. i have tried to place it in several areas resulting in the program crashing and am wondering if it needs to be placed somewhere after or before the loop? i have pasted what i have below minus this line [DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat("#%");] any help would be much appreciated. thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class FutureValueApp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("The Future Value Calculator\n");
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        // get the input from the user
        System.out.print("Enter monthly investment:   ");
        double monthlyInvestment = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter yearly interest rate: ");
        double interestRate = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter number of years:      ");
        int years = sc.nextInt();

        // convert yearly values to monthly values
        double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate / 12 / 100;
        int months = years * 12;

        // use a for loop to calculate the future value
        double futureValue = 0.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++) {
            futureValue = (futureValue + monthlyInvestment) * 
                          (1 + monthlyInterestRate);
        }

        // format the result and display it to the user
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        System.out.println("Future value:               "
                + currency.format(futureValue));
        System.out.println();

        // see if the user wants to continue
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.next();
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("Bye!");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The DecimalFormat class is a subclass of NumberFormat that allows formatting the string notation of decimal numbers according to predefined patterns. It can also be used to parse strings into numbers

To format a number, a template must be defined, which is a combination of special characters and text. There are eleven templates, but two of the most important are:

- 0: prints a digit if specified, 0 otherwise.
- #: prints a digit if specified, nothing else.

```java
String pattern = "###,###.###";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
System.out.println("Future value: "+ decimalFormat.format(futureValue));
```

To prevent the user from specifying a floating point number as year use a "try-catch" block to catch the Error

```java
try {
    years = sc.nextInt();
}catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid int");
     continue;
}
```